# Does anyone repair Flex radios other than Flex Radio?

Tags: software-defined-radio, equipment-troubleshooting, repair

A local ham that I have an evening sked with on 75m (Paul, W0EBV) sent his Flex 5000 SDR transceiver to  [Flex Radio Systems](http://www.flexradio.com/) to get it repaired a few months ago. However, it seems that **Flex is either unable or disinclined to repair it**.

Paul keeps getting the run-around and evasive answers from their official repair center. And the last time Paul called Flex, the repair technician asked him "What happened, did this radio get struck by lightning?!" *But nothing of the sort happened.* Paul unplugs the antenna, etc. whenever he leaves the house. And what is more, he was in QSO with me and the local SW MO group here on 3813 when it quit. The sky was clear, no lighting. His audio became distorted and then it ceased to function at all.

He bought it from another ham, and it worked great up to that time. Perhaps they have a backlog of radios to repair; but if that's the case, they have not told him that.

This is what I believe that Paul told me, on more than one occasion. ***And I believe what Paul told me***.

A Google search for 'flex repair service' shows up *nothing* (other than the Flex radio repair centers).

Paul has a dead radio and is at a loss as to what to do. How else can he get his dead Flex 5000 repaired?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99068/discussion-on-question-by-mike-waters-does-anyone-repair-flex-radios-other-than).

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but my friends recommend Troy Radio.  They are an authorized FlexRadio shop and specialize in the 5000.  You can reach them at:

**Link:**  [Troy Radio](http://troyradio.net/)
**Phone:** 254-239-3893
**Email:** toby@troyradio.net

I am not associated with Troy Radio nor ever used their service, but have heard they are good.

Comment: Hi Patrick, welcome to the site!